# .htaccess rewrite issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

I downloaded the phpmobilizer script and uploaded all the files to the server except .htaccess,because htaccess file was already on my server like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domainname.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain name.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain name.com.cp-11.webhostbox.net/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain name.com.cp-11.webhostbox.net$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain name.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain name.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain name.com.cp-11.webhostbox.net/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain name.com.cp-11.webhostbox.net$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|gif|css|js)$ - [F,NC]
```

But phpmobilizer .htaccess was

```
DirectoryIndex phpmobilizer.php


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ phpmobilizer.php?url=$1 [qsa]
```

i combined all the both code and site not working ...

Comment: the path of the url will be forwarded to phpmobilizer, there you can also parse_url($url) your url and you have the domain

Comment: What did the combined file look like? In what order did you put both sets of rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first block says -
Images hosted on your domain cant be used on other domains.
Second block says - 1. when filename is not mentioned (something/ ) open something/phpmobilizer.php 2. when requested filename or directory does not exists open phpmobilizer.php with querystring as well.
The first block should be present in .htaccess of document root(public_html/.htaccess). The second block should be present in the .htaccess of directory where phpmobilizer is installed. If phpmobilizer is in document root then second block after first should work. But it wont let open index.php or index.html